# Even after `sort`, `uniq` is still repeating some values

Tags: linux, posix, carriage-return, uniq

**Reference file:** http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Vote.txt.gz

(It is a tape archive that contains a file called `Wiki-Vote.txt`)

The first few lines in the file that contains the following, `head -n 10 Wiki-Vote.txt`

```
# Directed graph (each unordered pair of nodes is saved once): Wiki-Vote.txt 
# Wikipedia voting on promotion to administratorship (till January 2008). 
# Directed edge A->B means user A voted on B becoming Wikipedia administrator.
# Nodes: 7115 Edges: 103689
# FromNodeId    ToNodeId
     30          1412
     30          3352
     30          5254
     30          5543
     30          7478
     3            28
```

I want to find the number of nodes in the graph, (although it's already given in line 3). I ran the following command,

```
awk '!/^#/ { print $1; print $2; }' Wiki-Vote.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `/^#/` matches all the lines that start with `#`. And `!/^#/` matches that doesn't.
- `awk '!/^#/ { print $1; print $2; }' Wiki-Vote.txt` prints the first and second column of all those matched lines in new lines.
- `| sort` pipes the output to sort them.
- `| uniq` **should** display all those unique values, **but it doesn't**.
- `| wc -l` counts the previous lines and it is wrong.

The result of the above command is, 8491, which is not 7115 (as mentioned in the line 3). I don't know why `uniq` repeats the values. I can tell that since `awk '!/^#/ { print $1; print $2; }' Wiki-Vote.txt | sort -i | uniq | tail` returns,

```
992
993
993
994
994
995
996
998
999
999
```

Which contains the repeated values. Someone please run the code and tell me that I am not the only one getting the wrong answer and please help me figure out why I'm getting what I am getting.

Comment: Very good that you showed your efforts in your question. Could you please post sample of input and expected output sample in your question and let us know.

Comment: Dos line endings

Comment: Consider using "dos2unix" to fix your problems with the raw data, and see if your scripting now works as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file has dos line endings - each line is ending with `\r` CR character.

You can inspect your `tail` output for example with `hexdump -C`, lines starting with `#` added by me:

```
$ awk '!/^#/ { print $1; print $2; }' ./wiki-Vote.txt | sort | uniq | tail | hexdump -C
00000000  39 39 32 0a 39 39 33 0a  39 39 33 0d 0a 39 39 34  |992.993.993..994|
#                                           ^^ HERE
00000010  0a 39 39 34 0d 0a 39 39  35 0d 0a 39 39 36 0a 39  |.994..995..996.9|
#                     ^^              ^^ 
00000020  39 38 0a 39 39 39 0a 39  39 39 0d 0a              |98.999.999..|
#                                        ^^
0000002c
```

Because `uniq` sees unique lines, one with CR and one not, they are not removed. Remove the CR character before pipeing. Note that `sort | uniq` is better to `sort -u`.

```
$ awk '!/^#/ { print $1; print $2; }' ./wiki-Vote.txt | tr -d '\r' | sort -u | wc -l
7115
```